# trouble with event flow in Tk/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, wait, tk-toolkit

I'm putting something together using Python 3.1 and Tk.

I want to cycle through the different methods of the 'NewDataFrame' object I have defined here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import string

root = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

value = StringVar()
dataname = StringVar()

class MenuFrame:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.menuFrame = ttk.Frame(self.myParent)
        self.newButton = ttk.Button(self.myParent, text="new dataset", command=self.newClick)
        self.loadButton = ttk.Button(self.myParent, text="load dataset", command=self.loadClick)
        self.menuFrame.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.newButton.grid()
        self.loadButton.grid()

    def newClick(self):
        self.instructions = ttk.Label(self.menuFrame, text="enter a name for your new dataset")
        self.instructions.grid()
        self.nameEntry = ttk.Entry(self.menuFrame, textvariable=dataname)
        self.enterName = ttk.Button(self.menuFrame, text="enter", command=self.newData)
        self.nameEntry.grid()
        self.enterName.grid()
```

class NewDataFrame:

```
def __init__(self, parent, dataname):
    self.myParent = parent
    self.newDataFrame = ttk.Frame(parent)
    self.dataSet = DataSet(dataname)
    self.instructions = ttk.Label(self.newDataFrame)
    self.instructions.configure(text="enter aspects of %s, separated by commas" % (self.dataSet.getName()))
    self.enterBar = ttk.Entry(self.newDataFrame, textvariable=value)
    self.enterButton = ttk.Button(self.newDataFrame, text="ENTER", command=self.enterClick)
    self.doneButton = ttk.Button(parent, text="DONE", command=self.createAspects)
    self.newDataFrame.grid()
    self.enterBar.grid()
    self.goingOn.grid()
    self.instructions.grid()
    self.enterButton.grid()
    self.doneButton.grid()
```

I would like the doneButton to cycle through a few different commands, as you can see here in these methods of the newDataSet frame:

```
def createAspects(self):
    for asp in (value.get().split(',')):
        aspect = Aspect(self.dataSet.getName(), asp)
        self.dataSet.addAspect(aspect)
    for a in self.dataSet.getAspects():
        self.createFile(i=a.getName())
        self.instructions.configure(text="enter groups of %s, separated by commas" % (a.getName()))
        self.doneButton.configure(command=self.createGroups(aspect=a))

def createGroups(self, aspect=""):
    for gro in (value.get().split(',')):
        print(gro)
        group = Group(self.dataSet.getName(), aspect.getName(), gro)
        aspect.addGroup(group)
    for group in aspect.getGroups():
        self.createFile(i=aspect.getName(), j=group.getName())
        self.instructions.configure(text="enter members of %s, separated by commas" % (group.getName()))
        self.doneButton.configure(command=self.createMembers(aspect=aspect, group=group))

def createMembers(self, aspect="", group=""):
    for mem in (value.get().split(',')):
        member = Member(self.dataSet.getName(), aspect.getName(), group.getName(), mem)
        group.addMember(member)
    for mem in group.getMembers():
        self.createFile(i=aspect.getName(), j=group.getName(), k=mem.getName())

menuFrame = MenuFrame(mainframe)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm a big noob, but this took me a lot of work to produce and I'm really stuck where I am, so I could use some creative input.  I would like this program to pause the frame and allow the user to enter contents in the value variable for each of the following object types: aspects, which will contain groups, which will contain members (organized like a tree diagram).

Currently, the program doesn't wait at the createGroup level of execution (where I expect it to wait for another click in order to proceed to the createMember part) - and instead asks the user to enter members right after aspects have been entered.

I hope this isn't too abstract, thanks so much to anyone who tries to help.

Comment: It is not a matter of being too abstract or not. Instead, you have to provide the minimal code that reproduces the problem you are having.  By doing that it also helps you finding/understanding the problem, and others can effectively look into the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by looking at the primary error:

```
self.doneButton.configure(command=self.createGroups(aspect=a))
```

When Python reaches this line, it evaluates `self.createGroups(aspect=a)` and passes the return value to `command`.
So `self.createGroups(aspect=a)` ends up getting *called*. Instead, you really want to pass a callback function to `command` to get called later (when the `done` button in next pressed.)

Trying to manage the flow of control by reconfiguring the `done` callback is asking for trouble. Not only would we have to create functions with the right arguments (e.g. `aspect = a`) already bound, so we have a function which requires zero arguments the way the done callback expects, but also (and even harder) we'd have to recognize when to *reset* the `done` callback from createMembers, to createGroups, and back to createAspect. We'd be micromanaging the flow of control.

Wouldn't it be sweet if we could get Python to handle those details?

What you are looking for is a function that you can call, pause,  return to later, and resume at the point where you previously paused. 
Python has exactly this kind of function -- a [generator function](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/).

For example,

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        yield

mygen = gen().next
mygen()
mygen()
```

yields

```
0
1
```

Notice carefully that each time `mygen()` is called execution continues until Python reaches a `yield` expression. So the first time `mygen()` is called, `0` is printed, but the second time, `1` is printed. Python remembers where it last yielded, and resumes at that point.

So to apply this idea to your situation, you might try using something like this:

```
class NewDataFrame:
    def __init__(self, parent, dataname):
        ...
        self.on_done = self.cycle_done().next
        self.doneButton = ttk.Button(parent, text="DONE", command=self.on_done)

    def cycle_done(self):
        while True:
            for asp in (value.get().split(',')):
                aspect = Aspect(self.dataSet.getName(), asp)
                self.dataSet.addAspect(aspect)
            for aspect in self.dataSet.getAspects():
                self.createFile(i=aspect.getName())
                self.instructions.configure(
                    text="enter groups of %s, separated by commas" % (aspect.getName()))
                yield
                for gro in (value.get().split(',')):
                    print(gro)
                    group = Group(self.dataSet.getName(), aspect.getName(), gro)
                    aspect.addGroup(group)
                for group in aspect.getGroups():
                    self.createFile(i=aspect.getName(), j=group.getName())
                    self.instructions.configure(
                        text="enter members of %s, separated by commas" % (group.getName()))
                    yield
                    for mem in (value.get().split(',')):
                        member = Member(self.dataSet.getName(), aspect.getName(), group.getName(), mem)
                        group.addMember(member)
                    for mem in group.getMembers():
                        self.createFile(i=aspect.getName(), j=group.getName(), k=mem.getName())
            yield
```

This combines most of the code from `createAspect`, `createGroup` and `createMembers` all into one generator. It is possible to refactor `cycle_done` (into a generator that iterates over (smaller) generators) but doing so adds a bit more complexity to the solution. Let's get this solution working first, and then (if you are  interested) we can worry about refactoring.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction.  I'm going to work on this for a little while and see if it all sinks in.